# How to split content into different pages

Tags: 7, entities

How to split content into different pages.

node/test

into

node/test
node/test/features
node/test/images

Fields are grouped with Field group

Thanks,
Marius

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4439098/1520477) might help you. It should work pretty good and is flexible.

Comment: I tried, but I have some problems with the url rewrite. If I have node/10/features it's ok, but if I have node/test/features ( with url rewrite) not working.  Thanks

Comment: In path I have node/%/features . In contextual filters nid -> provide default value -> content id from url

Comment: how are you guaranteeing that the title (I assume) is unique across your node types?  Meaning, node/TITLE/features mapping directly back to one node?

Comment: I tried to use this article

http://peterpetrik.com/blog/node-id-view-argument-from-seo-friendly-url-path

In preview mode everything is ok, but when I try to display my view does not work,I can not not access the "view"
View can not be run because the parameter is not numeric ?
Only works if the parameter is nid

Comment: It's ok now.

error was generated by Sub-pathauto